# $a\frac{d^{3}x}{dt^{3}}+b\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}+c\frac{dx}{dt}+kx=0$, on what condition of k that we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$a\frac{d^{3}x}{dt^{3}}+b\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}+c\frac{dx}{dt}+kx=0$, $a,b,c$ are constant, and  on what condition of k that we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=0$

I completely have no idea how to solve this problem, can anyone could help me? Thanks very much!

What I did:

If we let $a=b=c=1$, then we have $r^{3}+r^{2}+r+k=0,x(t)=C_{1}e^{r_{1}t}+C_{2}e^{r_{2}t}+C_{3}e^{r_{3}t}$, since $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=0$, we get $r_{1}<0,r_{2}<0,r_{3}<0$. Assume that $r^{3}+r^{2}+r+k=(r+r_{1})(r+r_{2})(r+r_{3})$, then expand it we get $r_{1}+r_{2}+r_{3}=1,r_{3}(r_{1}+r_{2})+r_{1}r_{2}=1,r_{1}r_{2}r_{3}=k$, then how can I get the condition on k? I can just get $k>0$

Comment: if $\lambda$ is a characteristic root,then you want the real part of $\lambda$to be negative.

Comment: @abel I don't get your point, can you put more detail? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bf hint:$ the differential equation has a solution of the form $x = e^{\lambda t}$ if 
$$ a \lambda^3 + b \lambda ^2 + c \lambda + k = 0$$ for all solutions to have $\lim_{ t \to\infty} x = 0,$ the real part of $\lambda$ must be negative.

you can't too far without knowing more about the coefficients $a, b, c$ and $k.$

Comment: I did some work, but I cannot get the condition except k>0 if I assume a=b=c=1

Comment: @Jakoer, i don't think $k < 0$ is sufficient. for example take the roots $1, 1, -1$ the product is negative but you have two positive roots.

Comment: I got it, thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial is

$$ ar^3 + br^2 + cr + k = 0 $$

[Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) give us

$$ \left\{ \begin{matrix}
 r_1 + r_2 + r_3 = -\frac{b}{a} \\ 
r_1r_2 + r_2r_3 + r_1r_3 = \frac{c}{a} \\ 
r_1r_2r_3 = \frac{k}{a} 
\end{matrix} \right. $$

where $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are the 3 roots, which can be either all real or 1 real and 2 complex conjugates. In the case of 2 complex roots, their sum is a real number and their product is a positive real number.

In order for the limit to be $0$, the 3 roots must all have negative real parts, so $\frac{b}{a} > 0$. $\frac{c}{a} > 0$ and $\frac{k}{a} < 0$

All 3 conditions are needed, so you have to know more about $a, b, c$.

Comment: It's really helpful, thanks very much